# Qt c++ save object to a file

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to save an object called f to a file, getting errors: no match for operator << in stream << f

here is the function:

```
void FilmWriter::saveFilm(Film& f){
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this,("Save File"));
          if (fileName != "") {
              QFile file(fileName);
              if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
                  QMessageBox::critical(this, ("Error"),("Could not open file"));// error message
              } else {
                  QTextStream stream(&file);
                  stream << f;
                  stream.flush();
                  file.close();
              }
          }

}
```

Please let me know if you need any more information?
These are 2 functions in a different class filmInput

```
void FilmInput::getFilm(){
    Film f1(titleEdit->toPlainText(),durationEdit->toPlainText().toInt() ,directorEdit->toPlainText(),
             QDate::fromString(relDateEdit->toPlainText(),"dd/MM/YYYY"));;
    obtainFilmData(f1);
}

void FilmInput::obtainFilmData(Film &f){
    saveFilm(f);
}
```

Comment: Do you even have an `operator<<` to append instances of your `Film` class to a stream?

Comment: I think its because you cant add your class object to the stream, you need to break out film or add a film.toString() function or something that you write to the stream instead

Comment: added 2 functions, they are supposed to change the object into plaintext to save to the file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QTextStream` is made for storing text, not `Film`. You need something that can store your object. Maybe `QDataStream` will help you? But you'll need to serialize your `Film` object to something like `QByteArray`.
**Update:**
Now I see that you need `Film::toString()` method that will give you a string representation of `Film` object. Then you just write `stream<<f.toString();` instead of `stream<<f;`. 
Or you can implement `operator<<` that takes `QTextStream` and `Film`.
Example of `Film::toString()`:

```
QString Film::toString()
{
  return mTitle + " " + mDuration + " " + mDirector + " " + mDate.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

with the function below (which may not be 100% syntacticly correct) you can now write to your stream, `Film.toString()`

```
QString Film::toString()
{ 
    QTextStream stream;
    stream << someFilmVariable << " " << someOtherFilmVariable;
    return stream.string()
}
```

Comment: is this function meant to replace void FilmWriter::saveFilm(Film& f)?

Comment: No, in your film class add this function sorry got that wrong in the example above ill change it, the in filmWriter get this string thats returned from this function and then write this string to your textstream